# install Git slave on cygwin

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, git-slave

is it possible to get git slave running on cygwin under windows. I tried running `make` & `make install` with cygwin, however `make install` produces

```
mkdir -p //usr/local/share/man/man1 //usr/local/bin
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//usr’: Read-only file system
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//usr’: Read-only file system
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just place the gits script in my path and followed

http://sourceforge.net/p/gitslave/bugs/18/